# UnicodeDecodeError when trying to start the training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, utf-8, tfrecord

My study group has the task to train a network that detects cars with TensorFlow. We found a tutorial, that we thought seems easy enough:
https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-your-own-object-detector-ad69dda69c85
We got the images, we created the `.csv` files and tfrecord files and tryed starting the training process. This is the error we get:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 8: invalid start byte

We thing the problem comes from how we create the tfrecord files, but maybe somebody can point us in the right direction. The tfrecord files are like 300MB to 1,4GB big, so at least we know something gets created there.

How our `.csv` file looks like (we have ~3500 images):

```
filename,label,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax
SSDB00888.JPG,car,403.0,416.0,868.0,579.0
SSDB00889.JPG,car,46.0,419.0,303.0,539.0
SSDB00889.JPG,car,392.0,394.0,636.0,512.0
SSDB00889.JPG,car,819.0,367.0,1040.0,488.0
SSDB00890.JPG,car,553.0,419.0,1051.0,700.0
```

The code, how we want to create the tfrecord files. (We just copied from the tutorial of course and changed it a little bit, since we had different kind of label for our images). We tried changing the code in a few parts, but nothing really changes. We always get the error at the start of the training and we really don't know way.

```py
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import io
import re

import pandas as pd
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict


flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
flags.DEFINE_string('img_path', '', 'Path to images')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'car':
        return 1
    elif row_label == 'pedestrian':
        return 2
    elif row_label == 'bicycle':
        return 3
    else:
        None


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(re.sub('\s+', '', group.filename))), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    # check if the image format is matching with your images.
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    #classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        #classes_text.append(row['label'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['label']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs)
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):
        writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
        path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.img_path)
        examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input, sep=',', engine='python')
        grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
        for group in grouped:
            tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
            writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

        writer.close()
        output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
        print('Successfully created the TFRecords: {}'.format(output_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

The script gets called like this: `python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images\train_labels.csv --image_dir=images\train --output_path=train.record`

How can we solve the error? First time TensorFlow is way too complicated.

EDIT:
I have made some progress. I found out that my .tfrecords files seem to be `'ansi'` encoded and not `'utf-8'` encoded. Maybe that's why the error is thrown, but I don't know how to change the existing .tfrecord files or make new ones with another encoding.

Comment: Some tools report "ANSI" as if it were the name of a real encoding, but it's not; it's not even well-defined. *Probably* in this context it means  Windows code page 1252, but without a representative sample of the data, this is pure speculation. Perhaps see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: The various `__future__` imports look like you are using Python 2. It's 2021; you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same error. The problem was in the config file for training (eg faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config). I incorrectly specified paths in the params: "label_map_path" and "input_path".